# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol' of undefined in react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js:18258

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, relay

I am using the 'Rubix-Reactjs Powered Admin Template' for development(https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/rubix-reactjs-powered-admin-template-WB09498FH).

I installed the 'react-data-grid' adazzle plugin (https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid) using npm.

I have imported the below modules in my js files as follows:

- import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid';
- import ReactDataGridPlugins from 'react-data-grid/addons';

I get the following error logs in npm server when I import the 'import the 'react-data-grid/addons' component. The error is in the react-data-grid plugin file react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js.

```
[dev:server] /home/../alpha/tmp/webpack:/~/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js:18258
[2] var Symbol = root.Symbol;
[2] ^
[2] TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol' of undefined
[2] at symbolObservablePonyfill (/home/../alpha/tmp/webpack:/~/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js:18258:1)
[2] at Object.defineProperty.value (/home/../alpha/tmp/webpack:/~/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js:18243:1)
[2] at __webpack_require_ (/home/../alpha/tmp/webpack:/~/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js:30:1)
[2] at Object.defineProperty.value (/home/../alpha/tmp/webpack:/~/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js:18216:1)
[2] at webpack_require (/home/../alpha/tmp/webpack:/~/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js:30:1)
[2] at Object.exports.esModule (/home/../alpha/tmp/webpack:/~/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js:2413:1)
[2] at __webpack_require (/home/../alpha/tmp/webpack:/~/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js:30:1)
[2] at Object.exports.esModule (/home/../alpha/tmp/webpack:/~/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js:7536:1)
[2] at __webpack_require (/home/../alpha/tmp/webpack:/~/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js:30:1)
[2] at Object.exports.__esModule (/home/../alpha/tmp/webpack:/~/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js:7978:1)
```